# How to maintain scrollPosition of a div after it's children's style changes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

## Description

I am making a book reading app in react and i have a div called content-div, also that div has tens or even hundreds of p tags inside of it. and i need to maintain scroll position of user in that div in any case.

#### What i have done so far

i implemented a pinch zoom feature by detecting pinch gesture and incrementing body font-size 1px by 1px and it works pretty acceptable. but after changing the font-size of the body, naturally text size changes in the content-div and scroll position is lost. in order to prevent that i am recording scroll percent of the content-div by dividing current `scrollTop` to `scrollHeight - clientHeight` before font-size changes then rescrolling it into place. it works for the most part. but i realized if font-size is big enough to cause a wrap in the text scroll positions just go crazy. it overshoots the position or undershoots it. i mean the text in the page is always shifted somehow. i couldn't find any reason to not calculate the same value or not going to the same position.

#### Possible solutions?

There is a solution comes to my mind. can i anchor the screen to the most top left word in one of the p tags is that even possible?

#### What is not possible?

I cannot anchor the last p tag on the page to the top with using something like `IntersectionObserver`. Because i don't know the length of the text in that p tag. it could be hundreds of lines and overflows the screen. and user might be at the end of that tag. if i anchor it to the top the scroll position of user is lost anyway.

### Code

Disclaimer: I know with react i shouldn't mess with the dom but i couldn't think any other way.

#### Scroll position recording

this part is attached to the `scroll` event of that div

```
const contentDivTotalScrollHeight = contentDiv.scrollHeight - contentDiv.clientHeight;
const contentDivScrollPosition = contentDiv.scrollTop;
const newScrollPercent = clamp({
              range: [0, 1],
              number: contentDivScrollPosition / contentDivTotalScrollHeight,
          });
if (this.scrollPercentMap[contentDiv.id] < newScrollPercent) this.onScrollDown();
else this.onScrollUp();

this.scrollPercentMap[contentDiv.id] = newScrollPercent;
```

#### Rescroll afterwards

```
 async syncScrollPositions() {
    const contentDivs = Object.entries(ScrollController.scrollPercentMap);
    for (const [contentDivId, lastScrollPercent] of contentDivs) {
      const contentDiv = this.getContentDivById(contentDivId);
      if (contentDiv) {
        const contentDivTotalScrollHeight =
          contentDiv.scrollHeight - contentDiv.clientHeight;
        const targetScrollPosition = Math.floor(
          contentDivTotalScrollHeight * lastScrollPercent
        );
        contentDiv.scrollTo({ top: targetScrollPosition, behavior: "smooth" });
      }
    }
  }
```

My Dom tree looks like this

```
<div id="content-div">
    <img>
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="content-text">
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        /*...*/
    </div>
</div>
```

## Limitations

I don't want to use JQuery.